# changing from sqlite to parse

Tags: android, sqlite, parse-platform

I am trying to change all my functions from accessing sqlite to parse.
I'm new to parse and couldnt find any solution around.

I have successfully changed a function

```
public void register(String email,String password) {
    ParseObject o = new ParseObject("register");
    o.put("email", email);
    o.put("password", password);
    o.saveInBackground();
    //SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    //db.execSQL("insert into t_userInfo(email,password) values('"
            //+ email + "','" + password + "')");
}
```

currently working on the next function and would need some help

```
public Cursor login(String email,String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from t_userInfo where email='"+email+"' and password='"+password+"'", null);
    return cursor;
}

public Cursor findInfoByEmail(String email){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from t_userInfo where email='"+email+"'", null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off, you might want to look at the "parse" way to handle user registration and login, instead of writing your own logic.

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users

But, to answer your question. To fetch the data from Parse, you would do something like this.

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("register");
query.whereEqualTo("email", "<insertemailhere>");
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback() {
  public void done(ParseObject* object, ParseException e) {
    if (object == null) {
      Log.d("user", "The getFirst request failed.");
    } else {
      Log.d("user", "We got a object!");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: hi Hank, i am comverting my existing application from connection to sqlite to parse, therefore trying to reuse some of the functions and methods.

Comment: public Cursor login(String email,String password){
  ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("register");
  query.whereEqualTo("email", email);
  query.whereEqualTo("password", password);
  query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback() {
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
      if (object == null) {
        Log.d("user", "The getFirst request failed.");
      } else {
        Log.d("user", "We got a object!");
      }
    }
  });
  return null;
 }
how ever could not figure out the return value that will pass back the same values as my sqlite.

Comment: Parse will never return a cursor, you are better of not trying to mimic the old way. That never holds in the long run. Also, notice how the method actually returns via a callback-method. You could also run it as a blocking query (remove InBackground, see documentation.)

Comment: If you absolutely need cursor-like logic (you almost never should), you should impose a stable ordering & then add a > lastYielded constraint to your paginated results. Also, be aware that people who try to directly port a MySQL application to a no-SQL style backend like Parse tend to normalize their data more than appropriate in a no-SQL database. Be sure you partition your data by logical object boundaries rather than a hyper-normalized form you expect to JOIN into something useful.